# ZIP Archive sent by PHP is corrupted

Tags: php, zip

I am using php ZipArchive to create an zip file on-the-fly and send it back to the user.  I temporarily store the zipped file in a folder above document root and then send it back with the code

```
header('Content-type:application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.("file.zip").'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length:".filesize($file));
$fh = fopen($file,'rb');
fpassthru($fh);
```

after having first issued a

```
$zip->close()
```

to ensure that that the file isn't open.  The issue I have run into is this - the stored zip file is a valid archive which I can open in Windows 7, 7Zip, WinZIP etc.  However, when I send the file down with the code above it ends up with an 0xD 0xA pair at the start of the file which is enough to render it corrupt.  I cannot figure out where those characters could be coming from.  Is this a known bug with fopen/fpassthru?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Tip: there's [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) to output a file directly...

Comment: Does adding an `fclose($fh); exit();` at the end help?

Comment: Also, are you sure there's no other output? A BOM of the PHP file itself? Any whitespace?

Comment: You came very close Deceze - see my comment below.  If you had answered rather than commented I might have well accepted the answer.  I wouldn't have thought that an extra line after a terminating ?> in a required script would lead to so much trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does your full script look like?

Generally speaking you should remove any closing PHP tags at the end of your script files, as it's probably output coming from the end of your script, or an included script.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion David.  I typically work with scores of small scripts that get required and require_onced all over the place.  I went through the whole lot, commenting out one at a time and pinned down the problem - believe it or not it was down to an unrequired carriage return after a terminating ?> in one of those scripts!

Comment: Happy to help - best to omit the ?> as they're not necessary at the end!

Comment: @karl-gjertsen answer could help too

Answer (score 17):

I found when removing the `header("Content-Length:".filesize($file));` line it fixed my very same problem...

Comment: That worked for me too but WHY??? I had the same piece of code working for months before suddenly stopping and then by removing the line of code it started working again!

Comment: If that solved the problem then the reported file size may not match the download size. In such case bytes are missing/being added. In my case I didn't `exit;` the script and another script was printing extra HTML to the file. Simply `cat download.zip` and analyze the output of your corrupt file.

Answer (score 14):

After many tries to download zip file, the solution was:

```
$result = create_zip($files_to_zip,$fileZip,true,$path_parts['dirname']);
ob_clean();
ob_end_flush(); // more important function - (without - error corrupted 
zip)
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header('Content-Type: application/zip;\n');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fileZip)."\"");
readfile($fileZip);
unlink($fileZip);
exit();
```

Comment: ob_clean() and ob_end_flush() solved the problem, thanks

Comment: I tried `ob_clean()` and `ob_end_flush()` but it gives me empty zip file.

Comment: Yes, ob_clean() and ob_end_flush() solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@_on](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823780/on) ! 
You helped me with this information.
But instead of removing `header ("Content-Length:". Filesize ($ file)) ;`, I inserted a line break "\\n", leaving:

```
header ("Content-Length:". filesize ($ file). "\\n");
```

And the file generated its size to assist in the download
Okay then. 
Tks