# ZipArchive invalid in Windows only

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am using ZipArchive with the following code to create zip files. It works well in all browsers on a Mac. But it says the file is invalid on any browser on a Windows computer. I don't understand why. I emailed the supposedly corrupt file from the Windows computer to myself and opened it on my Mac computer, and it worked fine. I also read through all the suggestions on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620205/php-ziparchive-corrupt-in-windows) and tried all of them, with no luck.

Do you see anything wrong with my code?

```
if(extension_loaded('zip')){     
    if(isset($post['afiles']) and count($post['afiles']) > 0){   
        $zip = new ZipArchive();    
        $url = get_stylesheet_directory();
        $filepath = $url;        
        $zip_name = "DSV".time().".zip";                 
        if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){        
            $error .=  "Error";
        }
        foreach($post['afiles'] as $file){
                    
            // get the file directory url from the file ID
            $path = get_attached_file( $file ); 
            
            // add each file to the zip file 
            $zip->addFile($path, basename($path));  
    
        }
        $zip->close();
        
        ob_clean();
        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"'); 
        readfile($zip_name); 
        unlink($zip_name);
        
    }else
        $error .= "* Please select file to zip <br/><br />";
}else
    $error .= "* You do not have the ZIP extension<br/><br />";
```

I echoed `basename($path)` to confirm that there are no slashes. It is simply the filename like "this-is-my-file.docx".  Thanks for any insight!

Edit: The exact error in Windows says:

> Compressed (zipped) Folders Error
> Windows cannot open the folder.
> The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'C:\Users\krist\Downloads\DWV1620652983.zip' is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting the ZIP files, there's HTML coming after the ZIP content. The fix is to make sure to call `exit` as soon as possible after calling `readfile` so that nothing else is written to the stream.